# The response in iOS from JSON is not complete

Tags: ios, json, xcode

I have a problem with the response received by Json in iOs.
I don't know if it is because there is lot of informations concerning the WebService, but the response from Json is not good. I receive an answer, but when I check the string of the data with the variable NSMutableData *d, it is not complete, and in the *response, it can not init with the JSONObjectWithData.

```
    NSLog(@"Request: %@", bytes);

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]  initWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:10.0];
    NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[bytes UTF8String] length:[bytes length]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody: requestData];

    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

And the answer :

```
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSMutableData *d = [NSMutableData data];
    [d appendData:data];
    NSString *a = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:d encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:d options:kNilOptions error:&error];
}
```

Comment: Not complete? Are you sure? You're using UTF8 encoding to send data, and ASCII to read the received answer. Feel strange.

Comment: It is like the iOs doesn't wait enough to retrieve all the answer. Some times I receive more informations, some times I receive less. Very strange. In all case, it is not complete. Time out longer ? dispatch_async ? I don't know, nothing is resulting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `connection:didReceiveData:` delegate method is called whenever a chunk of data is received. There is no guarantee that you will receive the complete response in the first call.

The right approach is to collect the data in the `connection:didReceiveData:` and then process it in `connectionDidFinishLoading:`

Your code should look something like this:

```
...
self.receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
...

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [self.receivedData appendData:data]
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.receivedData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
}
```

Comment: Oh, I would like to complete, the answer is split in two. I retrieve the data in two times. It goes in didReceiveData: two times. I am goin' to do that you tell me, I confirm you in a few minutes. I think it will work.